# Is there a Maven flag indicating whether a build is a SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven

Is there a specific maven property indicating whether the current `project.version` is a SNAPSHOT or not?

Obviously this could be done by parsing the project.version string, but I'm interested in a specific property.

Comment: You want to retrieve the current version or to set the version as a snapshot ?

Comment: @yodamad I want to know if the current version is a SNAPSHOT, e.g. `${project.version.snapshot} == "true"` if and only if `${project.version}` ends with "-SNAPSHOT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${project.version.snapshot}` is not currently a supported property for Maven 3.

See [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Currently, there is an open feature request to add regex matching for profile activation. You may want to go comment and upvote the issue:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3826

The use case is exactly what you are mentioning:

> Activate a profile when project.version is not SNAPSHOT
>
> is it possible?

Comment: As you note, sounds like this would suit me perfectly.